# Does the function $f(x) = \frac{x^2-1}{x-1}$ have any point discontinuity?

Tags: continuity

Since the domain of $f(x)$ is $(-\infty, 1) \cup (1, \infty)$ is there any point discontinuity in $f(x)= \frac{x^2-1}{x-1}$?

Comment: you realise $$\frac{x^2-1}{x-1} = \frac{(x-1)(x+1)}{x-1}$$

Comment: Although $\lim_{x\to 1}f(1)$ exists, $f(1)$ is not defined, so there is discontinuity at $x = 1$.

Comment: No, it is not defined, so it is not discontinuous at $x=1$. If you defined $f(1)=3$, then $f$ would be discontinuous at $1$. @JamesPak

Comment: @ThomasAndrews "No, it is not defined, so it is not discontinuous at $x=1$" I don't quite get it. Continuity exists if and only if $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)$ exists and $f(a)$ is defined and $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)=f(a)$.

Comment: But it is not called a discontinuity unless $f$ is defined at the point. @JamesPak

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Oh I see. There is continuity or discontinuity only if $f(a)$ is defined.

Answer (score 2):

Rational functions are continuous in their domain.